# Nut + tuning instrument

Tags: strings

So I changed my strings for the first time on my electric and I accidentally wound my low E string the opposite way. I don't really want to get more strings and have leftovers. Will this hurt the nut or the tuning instrument in any way? And how will this affect drop tuning?

Comment: Do you mean it goes clockwise around the tuning peg?

Comment: Your Uncle Bob yes

Comment: You can probably remove the string carefully and put it in the other way around. Also, most shops sell individual strings.

Comment: Just unwind and rewind.  This string, being thickest of the bunch, is also most resilient.  Just don't ever tune it too high (but you probably know that)